# Small doubt in the proof of Hurwitz theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I was going through the proof of Hurwitz theorem from T. Gamelin.At one point author said sequence $\frac{f_k'}{f_k}\to\frac{f'}{f}$ converges uniformly on$\mid z-z_0\mid=\rho$.($f_k $ converges uniformly on above circle to f.) I checked wikipedia article article which said we can prove this by Morera's theorem, but I can't see how.The same question was asked but I am certainly looking for the argument which will use Morera's theorem. Any help. Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Morera's Theorem. Can you tell us which article in Wikipedia you are referring to? Actually this result follow immediatly from the fact that $|f|$ has positive minimum on  circle $|z-z_0|=\rho$ as long as $f$ has no zeros on the circle.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: In the proof section they have mentioned it.

Comment: If $h_k \to h, q_k \to q, |q_k| \ge a > 0, k > 0$ convergence being uniform on a compact set $K$, $h_k, q_k$ continuos say, then $\frac{h_k}{q_k} \to \frac{h}{q}$ uniformly on $K$; relying on Wikipedia for specialized math is always dicey as is relying on Wolfram alpha